# Rendering ListItem element shows blank

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native and trying to render ListItem elements from the react-native-elements library. I have the following piece of code:

```
renderLocationAndTrainList() {
    console.log('renderLocationAndTrainList');
    console.log(this.props.outboundTrains);
    return this.props.outboundTrains.map((train, idx) => {
      <ListItem 
        key={idx}
        title={train.station}
      />
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderLocationAndTrainList()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

When I render this in the simulator, nothing gets rendered, the screen is blank and there are no error messages either.

Console.log on the `this.props.outboundTrains` array shows the following in console:

```
[12:16:03] renderLocationAndTrainList
[12:16:03] Array [
[12:16:03]   Object {
[12:16:03]     "baseLocation": "Newhall, Harlow",
[12:16:03]     "createdAt": "2019-02-16T20:01:35.846Z",
[12:16:03]     "objectId": "8Z9jqYl5vW",
[12:16:03]     "station": "Harlow Mill",
[12:16:03]     "trainTime1": "7:25 AM",
[12:16:03]     "trainTime2": "7:50 AM",
[12:16:03]     "updatedAt": "2019-02-17T12:09:59.053Z",
[12:16:03]   },
[12:16:03]   Object {
[12:16:03]     "baseLocation": "Newhall, Harlow",
[12:16:03]     "createdAt": "2019-02-17T12:08:46.446Z",
[12:16:03]     "objectId": "vJGMw2xU2n",
[12:16:03]     "station": "Harlow Town",
[12:16:03]     "trainTime1": "7:48 AM",
[12:16:03]     "trainTime2": "8:02 AM",
[12:16:03]     "updatedAt": "2019-02-17T12:09:48.789Z",
[12:16:03]   },
[12:16:03] ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is not a duplicate of another question here, since the answer to that question does not address my question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the referenced question.

Answer (score -1):

You need return ListItem

```
return this.props.outboundTrains.map((train, idx) => {
  return <ListItem 
    key={idx}
    title={train.station}
  />
})
```

or change brackets

```
return this.props.outboundTrains.map((train, idx) => (
  <ListItem 
    key={idx}
    title={train.station}
  />
))
```

Comment: Neither of those helped unfortunately.